# Showing high priority items at top of dropdown list in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a dropdown list in `ASP.NET` with 100 items and out of these the probability the user will choose two of the items is high. So, I want to make these two items appear at the top like below,

```
Item 4
Item 6
......
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
Item 10
.
.
.
Item 100
```

But the user should not be able to select the `......` option. How can I do this in `ASP.NET` drop-down list? Is it possible to do this without duplicating these items?

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be like to add few most popular static items after the dropdown list populates from some database (if dropdown list is populating from database)

Like:

```
.
.
DropDownList1.DataBind();

DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("item 4", "item 4"));
```

This will add item 4 at the top of the dropdown list always.

**EDIT**

You can use jQuery on the front end to do this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#MyList option[value="item4"]').insertBefore('#MyList option[value="item1"]');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='MyList'>
  <option value='--select--'>--select--</option>
<option value='item1'>item1</option>
<option value='item2'>item2</option>
     <option value='item3'>item3</option>
  <option value='item4'>item4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: but this will make a duplicate of item 4 right, is there a way without adding duplicate? also i want to seperate the items above from the original list using a seperator

Comment: Alternative to this you can use "select 2 " plugin to add search bar to your dropdown so that user will be able to search the desired item easily.